# Duplicating Ubuntu from external hard drive to internal SSD?

Tags: installation, partitioning, macbook, external-hdd, ssd

I have been trying to install Ubuntu for the last few days and have had no success at installing to my internal SSD.  After trying to format it in Mac OS X and GParted (Which always resulted in a corrupted, unreadable disk), attempting to install from USB and CDs, and always having it fail at the installation phase, I decided to just install to my external.

Now that I have a working Ubuntu installation on my external, can I just partition my internal and then duplicate the partitions from the external disk? How would I go about doing this and would it be better to use Mac OS X or Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your SSD is not working correctly so you should sort out those issues first.  If you want to, you can just copy everything from the hd to the ssd.  Boot Ubuntu into rescue mode and go to a root shell.  Format the ssd, then mount it somewhere, and simply copy all of the files over, then update grub.  Replace sda1 with the correct drive:

```
mke2fs -t ext4 /dev/sda1
mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt
cp -ax / /mnt
blkid -p /dev/sda1
nano /mnt/etc/fstab
```

Write down the UUID that `blkid` reports, and change the UUID for `/` in fstab to match.  Then update grub and reboot:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
update-grub
reboot
```

When you reboot, grub should have an entry to boot from the ssd.  Make sure it boots correctly, and check `mount` to make sure that `/` is actually mounted on the ssd.  If it is, run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` and check the box to install grub on the ssd, then you can reboot, configure your BIOS to boot from the SSD, and recycle the Ubuntu partition on the HD.

Comment: I would use rsync instead of cp, as it gives you the ability to interrupt and resume the transfer.